# latex in a label

Tags: latex

I am trying to draw an arrow, and put two labels next to it, and the labels, namely `e_2`, and `a(e_2)` should be in latex format.

This is my try but it does not work.

Thank you.

```
p = Graphics[Arrow[ {{1, 1}, {1.5, 1}}]];

l1 = Graphics[Text[e_ 2, {1.5, 0.95}]]; 

l2 = Graphics[Text[a (e_ 2), {1.3, 0.95}]];

Show[p, l1, l2]
```

Comment: Take a look at the [MaTeX package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) by @Szabolcs

Comment: I prefer the MaTeX package, but control-4 worked for me inside `Text`/`Inset`.  MaTeX looks better. But when I tried it on the OP's example, the FE is stuck and the wheel of death is spinning....MaTeX has never done that to me.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that the variable `a` is evaluated when the graphics are typeset (see my answer below). What hung the FE was that the value of `a` was an array with something like a million elements.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL-4</kbd> (inline TeX input) works, although I prefer the actual TeX typesetting of [MaTeX](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/). I entered the TeX code `e_2` and `a(e_2)` into `l1` and `l2` respectively after typing <kbd>CTRL-4</kbd>:

[image]

However, somehow some of it gets evaluated (is that a bug??):

[image]

Wrapping the *inline cell* with `HoldForm` fixes the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Taking the comment into consideration -many thanks to @Lukas Lang

```
hh = a[Subscript[e, 2]];
p = Graphics[Arrow[{{1, 1}, {1.5, 1}}]];
l1 = Graphics[Text[Subscript[e, 2], {1.5, 0.95}]];
l2 = Graphics[Text[hh, {1.3, 0.95}]];
Show[p, l1, l2]
```

> [image: stack1]

Comment: I don't see how the `Format` line is necessary? Can't you just write `a[Subscript[e,2]]` in the second line?

Comment: @LukasLang, you are right. Thanks for spotting it. As I was trying things, I forgot to try the simplest one :)